# AspnetCore MVC - Javscript code for loading parital view is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to load different partial views based on the value inside view bag and for that I have tried the following javascript method :

```
function CheckAction()
    {
        var cat = document.getElementById('CType').value;
        var op = document.getElementById('OType').value;



        if (op == "Add")
        {
            if (cat == "State")
            {
                @ViewBag.PartialView="_StatePartial";                  
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the link to the view(cshtml file) : https://pastebin.com/XZPJBwp4

I have debugged the code and found out that the js code is working properly and viewbag is also getting the data but the only problem is that, the partialview is not being loaded. By default, default partialview is being loaded but once the button is clicked, the partialview should be changed that is not happening. please refer to this (https://pastebin.com/XZPJBwp4) view file to get the better understanding.

Here is the server side code from where the partial view is getting value(Controller Method)

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DataMgmt()
    {                         
           ViewBag.PartialView = "_DefaultDataMgmt";
           return View();          
    }
```

Comment: Show your server side code for getting the partial view as well as where you change it in the client.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that: The “ViewBag” is rendered at the same time as the page, so you can’t use this to load Partial View, I suggest you to use Ajax to achieve this function.

Delete the  and send Ajax in JavaScript:

[image]

Receive the Ajax and return the Partial View

[image]

(Partial View)

[image]

Then you can load the Partial View

[image]

Comment: Heyy @Chaodeng. Your answer is quite useful but I figured out another way out of this. by the way thank you so much for help!! :)